# how to preview data on page from a form in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I have a form having four fields and a checklist having checkboxes, 
now i want, if a user fills the form and select the checboxes, and press submit, it should go to a preview page, where all four fields would be shown in the form of labels and check boxes in the form of their values only, let me know how can i do it in a best manner with less pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the same page with a standard postback. The event of the submit button can hide the data entry panel and show a panel which dispays the values of the four controls as a preview.

Comment: which tag i should use for panel?

Comment: Asp:panel is the ui control. You can use its visible property to show/hide a panel on post back.